# Is there a way to export a variable to all levels of PIP dependencies?

Tags: python, shell, pip, dependency-management

I have a python project **Main** that depends of a private project **Client**, that depends of another private project **Base**. All projects are hosted on GitHub, in private repos, so to install them with pip I use the git syntax in the `pyproject.toml` files:

**Main** pyproject.toml

```ini
dependencies = [
    client @ git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/User/Client.git
]
```

**Client** pyproject.toml

```ini
dependencies = [
    base @ git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/User/Base.git
]
```

So, before calling `pip install main` I export the GitHub token to avoid the credentials prompt:

```bash
export GITHUB_TOKEN='my_token'
```

And this works as expected with the first level dependencies like **Client** but it doesn't seem to be exported further to deeper levels of dependencies, so I'm still prompted to enter the token manually when pip tries to install **Base** as a second level dependency.

My question is: is there any way to manage dependencies of private repositories with more than one level of depth?